# Нужны ли дополнительные знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли дополнительные знаки препинания в этом предложении?
Вы совершенство, лёгкая и элегантная.

Answer (score 2):

(1)  *Вы совершЕнство, **лёгкая и элегантная.***

Запятая поставлена верно. ***Вы*** — подлежащее, ***совершенство*** — сказуемое, ***лёгкая и элегантная*** — обособленное определение.

Определения, отнесенные **к личному местоимению**, обособляются всегда и в любой позиции (несочетаемость с местоимением).

(2) Возможна постановка **интонационного тире** при наличии паузы и  дополнительного логического ударения на подлежащем:

(1)  *ВЫ — совершЕнство, **лёгкая и элегантная.***

Comment: Вопрос, возможно, был и о тире.

Comment: Спасибо, поставим и тире тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы поставил **тире** *вместо* запятой: конкретные эпитеты приводятся не как уточнение (совершенство имеет абсолютный смысл и потому не требует конкретизации), а в обоснование высказанного умозаключения о совершенстве (почему захотелось так сказать):

> Вы совершенство - лёгкая и элегантная.